# What does Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t <- myActiveLinkDirective mean?

Tags: html, angularjs, gulp

Basically I am testing to see how a PROD version of my app is looking; I proceeded to run it through some gulp tasks (minify, strip unused css etc.) and got this error:

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t <- myActiveLinkDirective
```

Can anyone help with what's going on here?

This is some my angular code:

```
  var rustyApp = angular.module('rustyApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngRoute',
    'viewController',
    'mm.foundation',
    'angular-flexslider',
    'ui.router']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
          $routeProvider.when('/', {
        title: 'home',
        templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).when('/work', {
        title: 'my work',
        templateUrl: '/partials/work.html',
        controller: 'WorkController'
    }).when('/contact', {
        title: 'contact',
        templateUrl: '/partials/contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactController'
    }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    // configure html5 to get links working

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }]);




     rustyApp.controller('BasicSliderCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.slides = [
           '../images/sliderContent/1.jpg',
           '../images/sliderContent/2.jpg',
           '../images/sliderContent/3.jpg',
           '../images/sliderContent/4.jpg'
        ];

     });

     rustyApp.run(function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
     });

    rustyApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
            $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
        });
    }]);


    rustyApp.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'home';
    });
    rustyApp.controller('WorkController', function($scope) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'work';
    });
    rustyApp.controller('ContactController', function($scope) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'contact';
    });

    rustyApp.controller('OffCanvasDemoCtrl', function($scope) {});


    var OffCanvasDemoCtrl = function($scope) {};

    rustyApp.controller('ContactController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = 'hidden'
    $scope.resultMessage;
    $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
    $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
        if (contactform.$valid) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '../partials/mailer.php',
                data: $.param($scope.formData), //param method from jQuery
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                } //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result = 'bg-success';
                    if ($scope.result === 'bg-success') {
                        $scope.class = "bg-success";
                    }
                    // if($scope.result){setTimeout(window.location.reload(true),4000);}
                    if ($scope.result) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            window.location.reload(true)
                        }, 4000);
                    }
                } else {
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
                }
            });
        } else {
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
            if ($scope.submitButtonDisabled) {
                $scope.class = "bg-danger";
            }
            $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed Please fill out all the fields.';
            $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
        }
    }
});

var viewController = angular.module('viewController', []);

rustyApp.directive('myActiveLink', function($location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            path: "@myActiveLink"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
                if ($location.path() === scope.path) {
                    element.addClass('uk-active');
                } else {
                    element.removeClass('uk-active');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
// var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

// $j(function() {
//     $j('#Container').mixItUp();

// });

    rustyApp.directive('mixItUp', function() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            var mixContainer = $j('#Container');
            mixContainer.mixItUp();
            mixContainer.on('$destroy', function() {
                mixContainer.mixItUp('destroy');
            });

        }
    });


    rustyApp.directive('share', function() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
            // mixContainer.on('$destroy', function() {
            //     mixContainer.mixItUp('destroy');
            // });
        var $s = new Share(".share-button", {
          networks: {
            facebook: {
              app_id: "602752456409826",
            }
          }
        });

        }
    });

    rustyApp.directive('animationOverlay', function() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var modal = $.UIkit.modal(".modalSelector");

            if (modal.isActive()) {
                modal.hide();
            } else {
                modal.show();
            }

        }
    });
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    var rustyApp = angular.module('rustyApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngRoute',
    'viewController',
    'mm.foundation',
    'angular-flexslider',
    'ui.router'
]).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        title: 'home',
        templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).when('/work', {
        title: 'my work',
        templateUrl: '/partials/work.html',
        controller: 'WorkController'
    }).when('/contact', {
        title: 'contact',
        templateUrl: '/partials/contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactController'
    }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    // configure html5 to get links working

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);


 rustyApp.controller('BasicSliderCtrl', ['$scope', 
    function($scope) {
    $scope.slides = [
        '../images/sliderContent/1.jpg',
        '../images/sliderContent/2.jpg',
        '../images/sliderContent/3.jpg',
        '../images/sliderContent/4.jpg'
    ];

}]);


rustyApp.run(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
  });

rustyApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
}]);


rustyApp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.pageClass = 'home';
}]);
rustyApp.controller('WorkController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.pageClass = 'work';
}]);
rustyApp.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.pageClass = 'contact';
}]);
rustyApp.controller('OffCanvasDemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {}]);


var OffCanvasDemoCtrl = function($scope) {};

rustyApp.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = 'hidden'
    $scope.resultMessage;
    $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
    $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
        if (contactform.$valid) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '../partials/mailer.php',
                data: $.param($scope.formData), //param method from jQuery
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                } //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result = 'bg-success';
                    if ($scope.result === 'bg-success') {
                        $scope.class = "bg-success";
                    }
                    // if($scope.result){setTimeout(window.location.reload(true),4000);}
                    if ($scope.result) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            window.location.reload(true)
                        }, 4000);
                    }
                } else {
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
                }
            });
        } else {
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
            if ($scope.submitButtonDisabled) {
                $scope.class = "bg-danger";
            }
            $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed Please fill out all the fields.';
            $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
        }
    }
}]);

var viewController = angular.module('viewController', []);

rustyApp.directive('myActiveLink', ['$location', function($location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            path: "@myActiveLink"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
                if ($location.path() === scope.path) {
                    element.addClass('uk-active');
                } else {
                    element.removeClass('uk-active');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
// var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

// $j(function() {
//     $j('#Container').mixItUp();

// });

rustyApp.directive('mixItUp', function() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        var mixContainer = $j('#Container');
        mixContainer.mixItUp();
        mixContainer.on('$destroy', function() {
            mixContainer.mixItUp('destroy');
        });

    }
});


rustyApp.directive('share', function() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
        // mixContainer.on('$destroy', function() {
        //     mixContainer.mixItUp('destroy');
        // });
    var $s = new Share(".share-button", {
      networks: {
        facebook: {
          app_id: "602752456409826",
        }
      }
    });

    }
});

rustyApp.directive('animationOverlay', function() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var modal = $.UIkit.modal(".modalSelector");

        if (modal.isActive()) {
            modal.hide();
        } else {
            modal.show();
        }

    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

So I wound using [gulp-ng-annotate](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ng-annotate/)and it appears to add the syntax which was suggested below :) However when I try a PROD build I don't get any errors or anything, it just fails silently. Can anyone help?

Comment: Post your code. You have a dependency which is unresolved.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the "minify" part. Yes, Ates is correct below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*I posted the generic answer below before I had a chance to see the rest of the code you posted. Yes, indeed you have some controllers and directives that use inference. Change your code to use inline annotation, the `$inject` property; or less intrusively, use a tool like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) (thanks @deitch for the pointer).*

---

If you're minifying your code, don't use the inference style of dependency annotation. Use the `$inject` property or use inline annotation. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector.

### Example

Don't rely on inference:

```
function ($scope, $timeout, myFooService) {
}
```

Use either inline annotation:

```
[ '$scope', '$timeout', 'myFooService', function ($scope, $rootScope, myFooService) {
}]
```

Or the `$inject` property:

```
function MyFactory($scope, $timeout, myFooService) {
}

MyFactory.$inject = [ '$scope', '$timeout', 'myFooService' ];
```

This is because the inference flavour relies on the argument names of the function to be preserved (and match to existing services). You might be losing the original names during minification.

Comment: I would add that you don't absolutely have to use the inline annotation (which is ugly and violates DRY, albeit mildly). You can use ng-annotate.

Comment: saved time thx @AtesGoral. But I have to add this line too in production.rb **config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false)**. And then precompile assets again

Answer (score 9):

Set **mangle: false**.

This setting solved same problem that I had.

```
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

$.uglify({
  mangle: false,
  compress:true,
  output: {
    beautify: false
  }
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted anwser... Props to vukan for making My Project work: ihttps://github.com/amanuel2/ng-forum  ... Thanks a lot kind sir

Comment: This is awesome dude!!!!! this should be the accepted answer, was fighting with this for hours thanks!!!!